# Size of *p where p is a pointer to a 2D array

Tags: c

A simple C program:

```
  #define MAXROW 2
  #define MAXCOL 2

  int main()
  {
    int (*p)[MAXROW][MAXCOL];
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(*p));
    return 0;
  }
```

The answer is 16.
I don't understand how.

It follows this rule:

size = number of elements * sizeof (pointer variable, i.e 4)

Can anybody tell me how to analyse this expression so that the answer become obvious?

Comment: `p` is a pointer. It points to an array. `*p` is an array.

Comment: `size = number of elements * sizeof (each element ,i.e 4)`

Comment: what you need is : size = sizeof(p) / sizeof(int). 
then you will get 4 elements.

Comment: It is not clear what you don't understand. Suppose your code was `int a[2][2]; printf("%d\n",sizeof(a));`  That will also give you 16. Do you understand why that is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `sizeof(int) = 4` on your machine.
- `p` is an *array pointer* pointing at a 2D array of 2*2 int.
- `sizeof(*p)` gives the size of the type that `p` can point to, i.e. the size of the array.
- The size of the array = 2*2*4 = 16.

Comment: @mrigendra `*` always means the contents of the pointer, what the pointer points at. Array pointers are no different than other pointers, so if `p` is an array pointer pointing at an array, then `*p` is the array itself. (This particular array pointer isn't actually initialized to point anywhere, but that doesn't matter as long as we don't dereference it. When you take `sizeof` something, then as a rule of thumb, the size is calculated at compile time.)

Comment: so if p is a pointer to a 2d array then *p is the 2d array itself

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
int* p[MAXROW][MAXCOL];
```

and call `sizeof(*p)`, which is the size of an array of integer arrays

so `*p` is:

```
int[2][2]
```

and

```
sizeof(*p) == sizeof(int) * 2 * 2
```

An example to explain pointer and arrays:

```
int a = 2; //a is an integer with the value 2
sizeof(a); //4 because an integer on your system does probably have 4 Byte
int b[2] = {1, 2};
int *c = b; //1d array
assert(sizeof(b) == sizeof(c)); //size of 1d array = size of 2 integers = 8 Byte
assert(sizeof(*c) == sizeof(b[0]));// size of 1 integer = 4 Byte
```

Comment: i think int (*p)[2][2] is different to int *p[2][2]

Comment: @mrigendra nope, it isn't, print out `(*p)[2][2] == *p[2][2]` the parenthesis would change something if it was placed anywhere else, but the dereference operator is bound to p anyway and is equal to `p[0]`, as p is actually similar to `int[1][2][2]`

Comment: ok , but still they are different as first is a pointer to a 2 dimensional array and second is a 2d array of pointers..

Comment: (*p) and *p are equal. int *p[][] is a pointer to a 2d array while int p[][] is a 2d array, just like int *p[] is. But you must be aware of the difference between int *p and calling *p, because *p dereferences the pointer.